# Weakly-informative priors, complete separation and identifiability in Bayesian logistic regression

Tags: bayesian, logistic, prior, identifiability, separation

Where complete separation may result in non-identifiability of parameter estimates in Bayesian logistic regression, [Gelman et al (2008)](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/priors11.pdf) recommend using weakly-informative priors using a Cauchy distribution with centre 0 and scale 2.5 as "It has the advantage of always giving answers, even when there is
complete separation in logistic regression".

Using these priors, plotting the density of the prior distribution on top of the density of the posterior distribution for each parameter in my logit model shows that, at least for some of the parameters, the posterior is being influenced by the prior. I believe this means that these parameters are weakly identified. For example, [Garrett & Zeger (2000)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.0006-341X.2000.01055.x/abstract) suggest that a model is only identifiable if the  overlap of the posterior distribution with the prior distribution is less than 35% for all parameter estimates .

This mostly makes sense to me. Where I am confused is in interpreting the identifiability of estimates given these constrained priors. If the priors are essentially constraining the range of values the posterior can take, then should we not expect the posterior to look as if it has been influenced by the prior?

Comment: Do you have a mathematical definition of "weakly identified", or is it qualitative?

Comment: Other than the overlap of the prior/posterior density plots being less than 35%, it is qualitative. Basically if the posterior looks like it is being informed by the prior I suspect poor identifiability. I have a reference that details the calculation of the overlap, but would need to look for it in the morning (UTC).

Comment: Did these authors really mean this for a sparse data setting?